# MongoDB import/export indexes

Tags: mongodb

I need a tool for rapidly recreating the proper "schema" (such as it is) of MongoDB instances between environments that pre-creates the right DB names, collections, sets collection caps, and creates the indexes for each collection.   I do NOT want to copy all of the data between the instances, though.  Each env I manage has different data but the DB/collection/caps/indexes are all the same.  Is there an easy way to do this, preferably a tool that exports a JSON doc of all the names, caps and indexes that can then be re-imported into a new instance?

Comment: You would only need to import indexes and capped settings. Databases and collections are created implicitly when they are first used.

Comment: Right, all my collections are capped so I want them capped and created BEFORE any data is added.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ytkang/e3ac863f9e5ba3643d58becc8763cae3
I made a tool

Answer (score 7):

I wrote something today to just that. Exporting simply uses the API methods to call `list_indexes()` and `options()` on the collections of a selected database. Importing will create the database and create the collections with the indexes and options.

https://github.com/JonnoFTW/mongo-schema-export

It produces a file that you can use to setup indexes, caps and validators on another database.

Answer (score 5):

Once, I had the same problem too. What I did is a set of JS files which I had to run manually on each env (`mongo` can evaluate scripts). Those files had data inside so I had to manage them carefully not to introduce dups / corrupt existing data.

But then, I've found migration tools very helpful for such tasks. [This one](https://github.com/emirotin/mongodb-migrations) is my favorite, but there are [many](https://github.com/afloyd/mongo-migrate) [other](https://github.com/emerleite/mongo-migrate) [solutions](https://github.com/madhums/mongoose-migrate).

Think of you changes as of stream of immutable events. E.g: in order to drop previously created index you create new change (migration), which drops it. You store that stream as a set of files right in your VCS, so the setup for new environment is pretty easy (`mm migrate` and your base is up-to-date!) for new folks on a project. Also, this approach is very helpful when you work with containers or VMs: usually, you can trigger a script, based on container / VM life cycle, and thus populate the DB automatically, making restarts / recreations painless.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how these migration tools work. What I'm looking for is something like: 

`
mongoexport --indexes --caps -db MyDB -o MyDB.json localhost:27017 
mongoimport --indexes -caps -db MyDB -i MyDB.json localhost:27017 
`
Is there something out there that does this? If not, I can try and write it with python and PyMongo, but I'd rather use something off the shelf to save time.

Answer (score 5):

After I didn't find any appropriate tool, I dumped the database and restored it without data, so metadata is restored (particularly all the collections are created with apropriate indexes), but the collections are empty. This also can be applied to databases with data as well, so the indexes will be created on existing db if there is no conflict.

1.Make a dump with `mongodump`

2.Empty the data of collections

`find ./dump  -name '*bson' -type f -exec cp /dev/null  {} \;`

3.Restore the data to new db with `mongorestore`

Comment: why `cp /dev/null {}`, is not better `rm {}`?

Comment: as far as I remember mongorestore requires presence of that files, so you can not simply remove them

Comment: so 2. is “Empty the data of collections by replacing their files with empty files”

Answer (score 0):

All previous answers mention some workarounds, but there is an official way to export indexes.

As discussed on the [official MongoDB forum](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/does-mongodump-dump-all-the-data-indexes-of-the-collection/6197), using `--gzip` flag will include indexes.

Full command example:

```bash
mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://${USER}:${PASSWORD}@cluster1.gfixz.gcp.mongodb.net/${YOUR_DATABASE_NAME} --collection=${YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME} --gzip
```